# How I should to do with Cmakelist.txt if i want to link static lib and remove unused symbols

Tags: c++, cmake

Now I want to link 'libbz2.a' to my program，but when I compile the program, the size of exe will become twice as much as before.
The CmakeLists.txt is

```
find_library(Bz2_LIBRSRY NAMES libbz2.a)
....

target_link_libraries(${Bz2_LIBRSRY})
install( TARGETS
        ....
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
     )
```

For some reasons I can not use the shared library , only the static library, i know this gcc -Os -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections test.cpp -o test -Wl,--gc-sections can do it ,but I don't know how to do it in CmakeLi
So,how should i do with camke to make the exe become smaller? Thanks to all people answer it

Comment: If you add more code to your application it'll grow. What else do you expect? You could always link to a shared library instead of a static library if you're concerned about executable size.

Comment: Yeah, I know it ,but for some reasons  I can not use the shared library , only the static library, i know this `gcc -Os -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections test.cpp -o test -Wl,--gc-sections` can do it ,but I don't know how to do it in CmakeList

Comment: @puerileskull: "but I don't know how to do it in CmakeList" - Compiler options (e.g. `-fdata-sections`) can be added to [CMAKE_C_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html) variable or via [add_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_compile_options.html) or some other command. Linker options can be added via `target_link_libraries` command or via variable [CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.html).

Comment: Thanks ,bro, let me have a try

Answer (score 0):

If you care more about executable size, use a shared library instead of a static library.

```
find_library(Bz2_LIBRSRY NAMES libbz2.so)
```

And then link it to your `target`

```
target_link_libraries(${target_name} PRIVATE ${Bz2_LIBRSRY})
```

`${target_name}` will be replaced by the target name you have.

Also, `${Bz2_LIBRSRY}` seems like a typo to me.

> i know this `gcc -Os -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections test.cpp -o test -Wl,--gc-sections` can do it

You can do it like this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Os -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections")
```